# Range sensor does not detect objects in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, sensor, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and try to create an urdf file to represent my robot in rviz and gazebo, but I can't get the range sensor to detect objects in the simulator. The message at /arduino/sensor/ir_left always reports 3.75 as range, which is the maximum. For test, I added a gpu_ray scanner and that shows the object just fine in rviz. Spinning the robot in place doesn't help either, so it's doesn't seem to be the sensor angle.

What's wrong? Or any suggestion on how to debug this further?

The sensor definition is below.

Thanks, 
Joep

```
<gazebo reference="ir_left">        
   <sensor type="ray" name="ir_leftabc">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <update_rate>50</update_rate>
      <ray>
         <scan>
            <horizontal>
               <samples>1</samples>
               <resolution>1.0</resolution>
               <min_angle>-0.01</min_angle>
               <max_angle>0.01</max_angle>
            </horizontal>
            <vertical>
               <samples>1</samples>
               <resolution>1</resolution>
               <min_angle>-0.01</min_angle>
               <max_angle>0.01</max_angle>
            </vertical>
         </scan>
         <range>
            <min>0.01</min>
            <max>3.75</max>
            <resolution>0.02</resolution>
         </range>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_range.so" name="gazebo_ros_range">
         <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
         <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
         <updateRate>5</updateRate>
         <topicName>/arduino/sensor/ir_left</topicName>
         <frameName>ir_left</frameName>
         <visualize>true</visualize>
         <radiation>infrared</radiation>
         <fov>0.02</fov>
      </plugin>
   </sensor>            
</gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291726/range-sensor-does-not-detect-objects-in-gazebo/) by [Joep](https://answers.ros.org/users/35333/joep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-05-21**:
If you want to use GPU laser plugin the filename of this plugin is called `libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so` IMO instead of `libgazebo_ros_range.so`. The library should be saved in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib` location. Try to run gazebo in verbose mode to see if the plugin is loaded or not.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-05-21**:
Btw this is ROS related forum. For the future post Gazebo related questions [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/).

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-05-21**:
Also the type of sensor should be `gpu_ray` instead of `ray`.

**Comment by [Joep](https://answers.ros.org/users/35333/joep/) on 2018-05-21**:
@i4ncelot - thanks for your reply! I'm trying to create a sensor_msgs/Range topic, not laserscan. Laserscan works okay.
Tried to check the gazebo log at the location shown in the launch window. There are a few logfiles there, but none with gazebo in the name or with 'laser' or 'ray' in it.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-05-22**:
My bad, I thought you wanted to use the `gpu_ray` sensor. I've tried your model and it works for me just fine when I subscribe to `/arduino/sensor/ir_left` topic. Can you edit your question with the launch file you use? Have you tried to launch gazebo with `verbose` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Joep,
I think I found what happens to your range ray. The configuration is correct but it is very likely that due to the way that you have created your robot, the range is colliding against itself. Either it is colliding against the collision mesh of the sensor itself or either against the body of the robot. I cannot say which one because you did not publish the whole URDF.

Anyway, I created a video about how to detect that. Check it out here: https://youtu.be/Qq4Xsl-n3nM

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2018-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-05-22**:
Wouldn't the sensor report something like ~0.05 range when colliding with itself as shown in your video?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-05-22**:
Oh... if he has the collision box around the sensor greater than the max range it will return exactly the max range. I see it now.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-05-22**:
Yes l4ncelot. You can see at minute 6:24 of the video how the `rostopic echo` is providing exactly that value, reporting the collision with itself

**Comment by [Joep](https://answers.ros.org/users/35333/joep/) on 2018-05-22**:
Hi Ricardo, thank you so much for your video. Very informative. Add it shows my code could work!
However this is not the same issue. My sensor always reports 3.75 as range, which is the maximum. Is your robot model available for download? Would love to find out the differences with mine.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-05-22**:
The simulation is of the ROS Live Class that we do every Tuesday 18:00CEST online (open to anyone https://youtu.be/ajgwQ_lGFL4). In order to get it, create a free account at rds.theconstructsim.com and afterwards, click this link: https://goo.gl/rAovtd That will copy my project to your RDS account.